# Why can't I get photos/videos off Nokia phone?

Tags: camera, photos

I plug my phone into my computer (Ubuntu 14.04), go to Nokia phone and SD card, and move DCIM pictures to computer. Now I have some old photos on my computer, no photos in that directoy on the phone, yet I don't have my latest photos off the phone, and my latest photos are still on the phone, showing when I swipe away from the camera view.

In Storage Sense I have it set to put photos on SD card, music/videos/podcasts on SD card, downloads on my SD card, yet I can't see where in the world my latest photos/videos from the camera are.

Why is Windowsphone different from every other photo/camera device? what gives?

Comment: What other folders were visible? I've always seen the folder called "Pictures" and never as DCIM, but I'm not using Ubuntu either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photos will be saved in `SDcard->Pictures->Camera roll` folder and **not in DCIM folder**. You cannot locate the photos because you are looking in the right folder.

Your old photos located in DCIM folder must be taken from an digital camera / Android phone. Windows phone does not use that folder. It differs from other phones and camera in the stored location.

I use Ubuntu and a Windows phone and moving photos works fine.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it seems there is no way to get at videos recorded on the device?

Comment: @NoBugs Videos are also saved in the same Cameraroll folder.